# Why doesn't "AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut = true;" work for redirecting "post-logout" in the following context?

Tags: identityserver4

### The main application is a ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web Application using Razor Pages.

1. User accesses the application URL & gets redirected to IdentityServer4 login screen
2. User successfully login
3. User Logsout and gets redirected to "You have been logged out screen" of IdentityServer4 after successfully skipping the logout confirmation prompt.
4. This step fails: The user is NOT automatically redirected to the login page of IdentityServer4. He is instead redirected to a page where he is informed that he has logged off, here he is also asked if he wants to go to the login page, which is where i want him to be automatically redirected to without any prompts.

### What I have tried so far:

- In IDP >> Quickstart >> Account >> AccountOptions >> `public static bool AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut = true;` (this should be regarded as set to true the entire post)
- In IDP >> Startup >> ConfigureServices >> .AddOpenIdConnect >>
  `options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/signout-callback-oidc";` Adding this line of code did not help.
- I tried running using Chrome, Firefox, Edge - the issue persisted

### Code from IDP Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // adds MVC framework services 
            services.AddMvc();
            /*// adds services Razor Pages and ASP.NET MVC require
            .AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/index", "home"); });*/

            // dependency injection of services
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();                     // registers an IHttpContextAccessor so we can access the current HttpContext in services by injecting it
            services.AddScoped<IThisHttpClient, ThisHttpClient>();                                  // registers an "ThisHttpClient"
            services.AddScoped<IOrderService, OrderService>();
            services.AddScoped<IAccountService, AccountService>();
            services.AddLogging();

            // adding open id connect authentication
            services
                .AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
                })
                .AddCookie("Cookies")                                       // configures the cookie handler and enables the application to use cookie based authentication for the default scheme

                // The below handler creates authorization requests, token and other requests, and handles the identity token validation
                // "oidc" ensure when part of application requires authentication, "OpenIdConnect" will be triggered by default 
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";                       // matches the default scheme for authentication, ensures that succesful authentication result will be stored in a our applications "cookie"
                    options.Authority = "https://localhost:44370/";         // the authority is set to be the identity provider (the authority responsible for the IDP part of the OIDC flow), the middleware will use this value to read the metadata on the discovery end point, so it knows where to find different endpoints ad other information
                    options.ClientId = "3TL";                               // must match client ID at IDP level
                    options.ResponseType = "code id_token";                 // one of response type of the Hybrid ground to be used
                    //options.CallbackPath = new PathString("...");         // allows the change of the redirect Uri from inside the IdentityServerConfig (hand made class)
                    //options.SignedOutCallbackPath = new PathString("...") // 
                    options.Scope.Add("openid");                            // required scope which requires in sub value being included
                    options.Scope.Add("profile");                           // ensures profile related claims are included
                    options.Scope.Add("roles");                             // requesting a CUSTOM MADE scope (check IDP scopes/roles for details)
                    options.SaveTokens = true;                              // allows the middleware to save the tokens it receives from the identity provider so we can easelly use them afterwards
                    options.ClientSecret = "test_secret";                   // must match secret at IDP level
                    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;           // enables GETing claims from user info endpoint regarding the current authenticate user
                    //options.ClaimActions.Remove("amr");                   // allows us to remove CLAIM FILTERS (AKA this ensures the AMR(Authentication Method Reference) claim is dispalyed and not filtered out)
                    options.ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("sid");                // removing unnecessary claims from the initial cookie (session ID at level of IDP)
                    options.ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("idp");                // removing unnecessary claims from the initial cookie (the Identity Provider)
                    options.ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("name");               // removing unnecessary claims from the initial cookie (removing this type of data reduces the cookie size)
                    options.ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("given_name");         // removing unnecessary claims from the initial cookie (removing this type of data reduces the cookie size)
                    options.ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("family_name");        // removing unnecessary claims from the initial cookie (removing this type of data reduces the cookie size)
                    options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("role", "role");  // adding the CUSTOM MADE claim to the claims map
                    //options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/signout-callback-oidc";     // NOTE THIS DOES NOT WORK
                });
        }
```

### Code from IDP Config.cs

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
        {
            return new List<Client>
            {
                /// IMPORTANT: The client details declared in here must be matched with their exact copy on the client
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "3TL",
                    ClientName = "3 Tier Logistics",
                    //using hybrid flow to authenticate users
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,
                    // limits the URIs the user can be redirected to after getting authenticated or logging out
                    RedirectUris = {"https://localhost:44321/signin-oidc" },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44321/signout-callback-oidc" },
                    AllowedScopes =                                     // configures the allowed scopes for this particular client (aka what user info to share from all the available)
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        "roles"
                    },
                    ClientSecrets =
                    {
                        new Secret("test_secret".Sha256())
                    }
                }
            };
        }
```

### Code from Application Server Logout Page

```
public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        private OrderService orderService;
        private string targetUrlRegisterClient;
        [BindProperty]
        public Client Client { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            Task.Run(() => HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies"));
            Task.Run(() => HttpContext.SignOutAsync("oidc"));
        }

        public void OnPost()
        {
            targetUrlRegisterClient = "http://localhost:8080/server_war_exploded/root/api/registerclient";
            orderService = new OrderService();
            Task<string> response = orderService.PostRegisterClientAsync(Client, targetUrlRegisterClient);
        }
    }
```

### Debug output of logout hit

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:44321/Login  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker:Information: Route matched with {page = "/Login"}. Executing page /Login
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker:Information: Executing handler method Client_Customer.Pages.LoginModel.OnGet with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker:Information: Executed handler method OnGet, returned result .
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker:Information: Executing an implicit handler method - ModelState is Valid
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker:Information: Executed an implicit handler method, returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.PageResult.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler:Information: AuthenticationScheme: oidc signed out.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies signed out.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker:Information: Executed page /Login in 69.7362ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44370/connect/endsession?post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44321%2Fsignout-callback-oidc&id_token_hint=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjA5MmI0Yjk0MjQzNjJiZmQ3ZWM3Y2MyMDU1NGFiMTZlIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJuYmYiOjE1NTc5MDkzNzAsImV4cCI6MTU1NzkwOTY3MCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NDQzNzAiLCJhdWQiOiIzVEwiLCJub25jZSI6IjYzNjkzNTA2MTYwMzY3NjQyMC5ZMkl6WTJReVlqRXRZMlF5TXkwME5UTmlMVGhpWkdFdFlqQTBNRGsxTVRWak1qazRNak5rTVdaaU1XRXRNV1EwTXkwME0yVTBMVGsxTlRNdFlUTmpZalEwWlRVd1pHSm0iLCJpYXQiOjE1NTc5MDkzNzAsImF0X2hhc2giOiJWWHVYRHJZcTZNWnF3X2N2T0h3eDNnIiwic2lkIjoiNGViNzQ5ZjA5ZGQ4MjNkNzI5NmQzMjU1NWU5MGJiMDYiLCJzdWIiOiIyMjIyIiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNTU3OTA5MzY3LCJpZHAiOiJsb2NhbCIsImFtciI6WyJwd2QiXX0.NzqA4kILvZgjlTd6dhku6827dG-_9MkJpAH11inQ0-biR0GXP7fkrklIRy8DgxDh8zEriNMUSM8gd9E_p7Zn4hn-HRZ5MJf1hOHfyo3Pdih0sgZ6eNzOvAManiLgNb85n6hcNx04H7PRLHjlZOR01dYkjZrnRCNTWLnVlrsu3xmnonagOtvtF5a_QuZqVJvUedqxby95RH-U5AuqW2pdPTQfzQVZBvUXrAdJGj6wOXwHCn9TSpRJcH4OPtWOMvP8Z84Iiz8vH_lK_qtBUkcSmjs_kOt_qFeGYgDE_xv71HMa0HhcbJlQ-GPwTJu2cA0teGUby33Sj-td92A7y1v5mQ&state=CfDJ8IMSTeB9liZHhYIais0HVw5svLoMCzrej-fgkjkCV_TaQjqMXAXfoVdkgkWNdpnCfCNjv9hXQ_qcU3uSC7KVbJaFghyxVZD1b3eL8Yeb_G8gnDDGoJYODAljLU_pki5M9aZbR_UbjmpgodcofaWnccPgRlLOf3nSTH1eiS2zoe8n&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=5.3.0.0  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 94.0857ms 302 text/html; charset=utf-8
IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter:Debug: Request path /connect/endsession matched to endpoint type Endsession
IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter:Debug: Endpoint enabled: Endsession, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionEndpoint
IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware:Information: Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionEndpoint for /connect/endsession
IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionEndpoint:Debug: Processing signout request for 2222
IdentityServer4.Validation.EndSessionRequestValidator:Debug: Start end session request validation
IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenValidator:Debug: Start identity token validation
IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore:Debug: client configuration validation for client 3TL succeeded.
IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenValidator:Debug: Client found: 3TL / 3 Tier Logistics
IdentityServer4.Test.TestUserProfileService:Debug: IsActive called from: IdentityTokenValidation
IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenValidator:Debug: Calling into custom token validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultCustomTokenValidator
IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenValidator:Debug: Token validation success
{
  "ClientId": "3TL",
  "ClientName": "3 Tier Logistics",
  "ValidateLifetime": false,
  "Claims": {
    "nbf": 1557909370,
    "exp": 1557909670,
    "iss": "https://localhost:44370",
    "aud": "3TL",
    "nonce": "636935061603676420.Y2IzY2QyYjEtY2QyMy00NTNiLThiZGEtYjA0MDk1MTVjMjk4MjNkMWZiMWEtMWQ0My00M2U0LTk1NTMtYTNjYjQ0ZTUwZGJm",
    "iat": 1557909370,
    "at_hash": "VXuXDrYq6MZqw_cvOHwx3g",
    "sid": "4eb749f09dd823d7296d32555e90bb06",
    "sub": "2222",
    "auth_time": 1557909367,
    "idp": "local",
    "amr": "pwd"
  }
}
IdentityServer4.Validation.EndSessionRequestValidator:Information: End session request validation success
{
  "ClientId": "3TL",
  "ClientName": "3 Tier Logistics",
  "SubjectId": "2222",
  "PostLogOutUri": "https://localhost:44321/signout-callback-oidc",
  "State": "CfDJ8IMSTeB9liZHhYIais0HVw5svLoMCzrej-fgkjkCV_TaQjqMXAXfoVdkgkWNdpnCfCNjv9hXQ_qcU3uSC7KVbJaFghyxVZD1b3eL8Yeb_G8gnDDGoJYODAljLU_pki5M9aZbR_UbjmpgodcofaWnccPgRlLOf3nSTH1eiS2zoe8n",
  "Raw": {
    "post_logout_redirect_uri": "https://localhost:44321/signout-callback-oidc",
    "id_token_hint": "***REDACTED***",
    "state": "CfDJ8IMSTeB9liZHhYIais0HVw5svLoMCzrej-fgkjkCV_TaQjqMXAXfoVdkgkWNdpnCfCNjv9hXQ_qcU3uSC7KVbJaFghyxVZD1b3eL8Yeb_G8gnDDGoJYODAljLU_pki5M9aZbR_UbjmpgodcofaWnccPgRlLOf3nSTH1eiS2zoe8n",
    "x-client-SKU": "ID_NETSTANDARD2_0",
    "x-client-ver": "5.3.0.0"
  }
}
IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionEndpoint:Debug: Success validating end session request from 3TL
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 60.2054ms 302 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44370/Account/Logout?logoutId=CfDJ8IMSTeB9liZHhYIais0HVw7kc9GyTnHxoDNbRDCp7qA3cjwUvTmwOc8iOz2QeBz21IjWognFICseoXkQwH-eQJtXY9bWxa1vP3GLUz98cWKI1VMcnArspUbxRT9bcUF1ZrmloS7t_Us-uV9Ipa-VkgSUmLZfXAWa2f-WXPIv3VRmGwLNV7dqQa_pQOTkyDoiW_ddGElcwit15bJ3BLS6f52dYIU5fzjlSBtzGqT516-usiS-wmfacbACtJQn1VaEahKiBnW7X1gI4PRhQhCZF-IFzeXjESuMigwFyUay7K79DOZCqJ7ReU-RZ7GR1TsFsnqS8212Dr10hkznljRMnDeB6CZbB87LorJxZvf_eH33NBhzJzCZ1bwvPoz_vJeQoHO50P1IfNUGZjO8Y7pYimUC52SCe0jCKUUF8a5t_HZHMNVvtoCgC8b42zHE9rM5ms25BWLTFsgQH6wJFG09fmI5Eu_ICWCTm7XbQxMsBLK8cXdyIb_g1ccqaoz1gohMtpfciokB5_xInN1EcResbtkRUNeLO5DN_c5aFX5QZrC-HJVqxLAdKzZ4coL-x06s8Emvu9w3S1ZjlYLZCPMKHfK1LKgAFnqq1rUEV9PDtwmWDe_gz9ga45MHyMYrrFTswq2ut2gylVFbnb9nEt-g4OWzC6Mqi1mq6Y9CmWefYDwmbsyO-hM9r-p3bZVgYCJkw77zP0UDzFndpM_82gwMau8PH85qxEk1Hz3kJJxilbvAOX1lowfBBymXZH1M0qaiIVS0V2MPL19ySkhIiBQZs7rYcsXMU-wILzhm_729Xt9TxUwZxRFgwngE2fFizgyG_g  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Route matched with {action = "Logout", controller = "Account"}. Executing action IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.Logout (IdentityServer)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executing action method IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.Logout (IdentityServer) with arguments (CfDJ8IMSTeB9liZHhYIais0HVw7kc9GyTnHxoDNbRDCp7qA3cjwUvTmwOc8iOz2QeBz21IjWognFICseoXkQwH-eQJtXY9bWxa1vP3GLUz98cWKI1VMcnArspUbxRT9bcUF1ZrmloS7t_Us-uV9Ipa-VkgSUmLZfXAWa2f-WXPIv3VRmGwLNV7dqQa_pQOTkyDoiW_ddGElcwit15bJ3BLS6f52dYIU5fzjlSBtzGqT516-usiS-wmfacbACtJQn1VaEahKiBnW7X1gI4PRhQhCZF-IFzeXjESuMigwFyUay7K79DOZCqJ7ReU-RZ7GR1TsFsnqS8212Dr10hkznljRMnDeB6CZbB87LorJxZvf_eH33NBhzJzCZ1bwvPoz_vJeQoHO50P1IfNUGZjO8Y7pYimUC52SCe0jCKUUF8a5t_HZHMNVvtoCgC8b42zHE9rM5ms25BWLTFsgQH6wJFG09fmI5Eu_ICWCTm7XbQxMsBLK8cXdyIb_g1ccqaoz1gohMtpfciokB5_xInN1EcResbtkRUNeLO5DN_c5aFX5QZrC-HJVqxLAdKzZ4coL-x06s8Emvu9w3S1ZjlYLZCPMKHfK1LKgAFnqq1rUEV9PDtwmWDe_gz9ga45MHyMYrrFTswq2ut2gylVFbnb9nEt-g4OWzC6Mqi1mq6Y9CmWefYDwmbsyO-hM9r-p3bZVgYCJkw77zP0UDzFndpM_82gwMau8PH85qxEk1Hz3kJJxilbvAOX1lowfBBymXZH1M0qaiIVS0V2MPL19ySkhIiBQZs7rYcsXMU-wILzhm_729Xt9TxUwZxRFgwngE2fFizgyG_g) - Validation state: Valid
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler:Information: AuthenticationScheme: idsrv signed out.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action method IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.Logout (IdentityServer), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult in 24.8267ms.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor:Information: Executing ViewResult, running view LoggedOut.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor:Information: Executed ViewResult - view LoggedOut executed in 19.1822ms.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.Logout (IdentityServer) in 48.1906ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 59.083ms 200 text/html; charset=utf-8
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44370/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44370/icon.png  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44370/lib/jquery/jquery.js  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 17.4182ms 404 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 16.464ms 404 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44370/css/site.css  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 20.1358ms 404 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 8.4111ms 404 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44370/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44370/js/signout-redirect.js  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44370/connect/endsession/callback?endSessionId=CfDJ8IMSTeB9liZHhYIais0HVw4UP5MHpGg4UIrZ1rPYhDNKZ0T8aLNc6sQ00tDxQN7898mdUQGymNjElfE09nHu53Jcmj2OlrmLZdqwrS33_ea8BVUC1KpYuh1NtSAGTbqHF-Z4GVqWLIM3--4-kv1Jwggs2PBPjytq65cjCge00Zg2lNQEsKjgNxupv-gNwSWvdklOEQ9gRuGAd8dTXhUJqHomK7a87OWqQvuE1hQieeDesgtCSaVhC9-CcaEJycYkOkmyrxFrOWG4Npw6smPd-XU  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 7.3577ms 404 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 7.7551ms 404 
IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter:Debug: Request path /connect/endsession/callback matched to endpoint type Endsession
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.2.4\System.Net.Security.dll'. Symbols loaded.
IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter:Debug: Endpoint enabled: Endsession, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionCallbackEndpoint
IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware:Information: Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionCallbackEndpoint for /connect/endsession/callback
IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionCallbackEndpoint:Debug: Processing signout callback request
IdentityServer4.Stores.ValidatingClientStore:Debug: client configuration validation for client 3TL succeeded.
IdentityServer4.Validation.EndSessionRequestValidator:Debug: No client front-channel logout URLs
IdentityServer4.Validation.EndSessionRequestValidator:Debug: No client back-channel logout URLs
IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionCallbackEndpoint:Information: Successful signout callback.
IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionCallbackEndpoint:Debug: No client front-channel iframe urls
IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionCallbackEndpoint:Debug: No client back-channel iframe urls
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 103.2685ms 200 text/html; charset=UTF-8
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44370/favicon.ico  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 1.9017ms 404 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44370/favicon.ico  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 2.2642ms 404 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44370/favicon.ico  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 2.4325ms 404
```

### The core problem:

I want to be redirected to the login page of the IDP which i can not currently achieve, and i need help to understand what am I doing wrong.

P.S. I am 3rd semester at IT University and this is the first time I am using IndetityServer4, I hope to use it for all my future applications, thank you for your patience.

Comment: `This step fails: The user is not automatically redirected to the login page of IdentityServer4`: where is the user redirected? You need some sort of redirect logic on you logout page to achieve what you want to do. The redirect url can be hard coded there or it can come from your client configuration.

Comment: There is a standard login page of IdentityServer4 that comes with a Quickstart folder. According to the documentation i read and tutorials i followed.
`AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut = true;` should automatically redirect me to that page. He is instead redirected to a page where he is informed that he has logged off, here he is also asked if he wants to go to the login page, which is where i want him to be automatically redirected to without any prompts.

Comment: The user's probably redirected here then: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/master/Views/Account/LoggedOut.cshtml Make sure you have the `PostLogoutRedirectUri ` setup for your `3TL` client

Comment: You might have missed my problem, I WANT to be redirected to the IDP login page, but i don't get redirected there, instead I get redirected to the IDP "LoggedOut" page. Which according to the tutorial on Pluralsight is not the expected behavior. I can see there is:
`@section scripts
{
    @if (Model.AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut)
    {
        <script src="~/js/signout-redirect.js"></script>
    }
}`

But I do not know what is inside that .js file or where I can find it.

Comment: If you are using the quickstart pretty much verbatim you need to setup the `PostLogoutRedirectUri` for your client (you can set it up to the login page if you want) and then the view I linked earlier will take care of redirecting you there. I don't know the pluralsight course on the subject so I can't tell you what's in the js file but it's probably something that looks like what is done in the quickstart loggedout view.

Comment: If i understood you correctly then I have already done that if you look at my Config.cs code.

Comment: In this case, 2 things: check that the value you have is what you want (is your login url really `"https://localhost:44321/signout-callback-oidc"`?) and also make sure that the `logoutid` (or whatever name you have for the logout context parameter https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/master/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs#L178) is set and valid.

Comment: I'm sorry to say but when i changed `"https://localhost:44321/signout-callback-oidc"` to `"https://localhost:44321/signin-oidc"` which is the redirect Uri for login it doesnt not work. What happens is that now I am simply notified that I have logged out but i no longer have the option to click for being redirected to the login page of the IDP. Still need HELP

Comment: Also I am using Quickstart files from IdentityServer4 official website, not tutorial specific docs.

Comment: Where is this code: `@section scripts { @if (Model.AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut) { <script src="~/js/signout-redirect.js"></script> } }` coming from then? I don't think it's in the quickstart ui. If you use exactly what is in the quickstart ui it works. Otherwise show us what you have for this view https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/master/Views/Account/LoggedOut.cshtml and this controller https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/master/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs

Comment: `@section scripts
{
    @if (Model.AutomaticRedirectAfterSignOut)
    {
        <script src="~/js/signout-redirect.js"></script>
    }
}` is present in my Quickstart >> Views >> Account >> LoggedOut.cshtml the controller looks exactly like the one you linked. :( I'll put a breackpoint there and check.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the signout-redirect.js:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var a = document.querySelector("a.PostLogoutRedirectUri");
    if (a) {
        window.location = a.href;
    }
});
```